# Need help in java swings, creating a simple form

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to java swings . Actually I have the below cases :

```
Case1 : “the collection was guaranteed.i'm sure it is” 
Case2 :  the collection was guaranteed.i'm sure it is
Case2 :  the collection was guaranteed...i'm sure it is
```

These cases i want to reflect using a swing window.Which will accept these cases.

Conditions :

In `case1` , since the text is surrounded by "" it should not do anything.

second case, since the data is not surrounded by "", the "." should be highlighted (if the "." is single) in yellow.

In 3rd case sine the "." is preceded or followed by another "." it should be left as it is.

someone suggested me that this can be done using swings, please give me an idea about how to proceed. Here i want to have a form in which we can paste this text and a button named "Clean", once it is hit, the yellow highlight should come on the period. please also suggest me some good references to swings.

What i have tried is as below. this is not done fully as i wasn't aware of how to start it and how to proceed

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**

 * @author u0138039
 */
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJPanel
     */
    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
        createGUI();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("Clean");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(472, 472, 472)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(579, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 367, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 398, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
        jTextArea2=jTextArea1.getText();
 Scanner scan=new Scanner(jTextArea1.getText());
    System.out.println("enter some text \n");
    String line= scan.nextLine();
   if(line.contains("\""))
   {
       System.out.println("Notining to do");
       System.exit(0);
   }
    int dot1=  line.indexOf(".");
    int dot2=line.lastIndexOf(".");
    if(dot1==dot2)
    {
       jTextArea2.setText(line);
            try {
                hilit.addHighlight(dot1,dot1+1, painter);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
       jFrame1.setVisible(true);
    }
    if(dot1==dot1+dot2 || dot1==dot2-dot1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jFrame1,"2 dots");
    }
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private Highlighter hilit=null;
    private  final Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.yellow);

    private void createGUI() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're misunderstanding *swing*.

Comment: and what is "swings"? I'm feeling really bad and sad that you're given a homework assignment on technologies you can't even spell and understand.

Comment: Swing is a graphical user interface builder / framework. What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: Hi all, sorry for my bad language. Hi @MaxLeske: i actually whant the tasks i said in my question to be done in swing framework.

Comment: @Marsoni Nm Can you be more clear??

Comment: One place to start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: @MarsoniNm I still don't understand what you mean. Your example simply shows some strings... Are the `Case` statements meant to clarify your cases or are they meant to be case statements in the Java language? I assume the first. If so, I'd first start learning Swing so far that you can display the strings. Coloring the strings based on an algorithm will then become more clear and easy. Have a look at this page for help on Swing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/

Comment: @MaxLeske: they are just case statements to show it as 3 different cases that has nothing to do with the question.Thanks

Comment: Ok...got it..will try out something before the question is closed.

Comment: See my answer, was that you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Not having much swing experience, the simplest way is using HTML.

Use a JTextPane (or JEditorPane).

```
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
```

If setting by code, make sure the string begins with `"<html>"`:

```
textPane.setText("<html>“the collection was guaranteed.i'm sure it is”");
```

Now you can use HTML for mark up, colouring and such:

```
"~~~<span style='background-color:#ffff00'>.</span>~~~"
```

A document change listener, or key listener may add the markup every time anew.

```
Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
String plainText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
```

For the logic regular expressions can be used, i.a. with so called lookahead. A separate chapter.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a short example.

- Use proper LayoutManager as per your needs
- I have checked your most cases, may be not all
- I have used a `Highlighter` to highlight '.'

[image]

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
    import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
    import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;




    /**
     *
     * @author rohan
     */
    public class TestPeriodHighlight {
        private JFrame frame;
        private JPanel panel;
        private JTextArea jTextArea;
        private JButton butt;
        private Highlighter hilit=null;
        private  final Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.yellow);
    TestPeriodHighlight () throws BadLocationException
    {
    createGUI();
    process();
    }
    public void process() throws BadLocationException
    {
     hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
     jTextArea.setHighlighter(hilit);
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter some text \n");
        String line= scan.nextLine();
       if(line.contains("\""))
       {
           System.out.println("Notining to do");
           System.exit(0);
       }
        int dot1=  line.indexOf(".");
        int dot2=line.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(dot1==dot2)
        {
           jTextArea.setText(line);
           hilit.addHighlight(dot1,dot1+1, painter);
           frame.setVisible(true);
        }



    }
    public void createGUI()
    {
    butt=new JButton("clear");
    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel=new JPanel();
    jTextArea=new JTextArea(20,20);
    panel.add(jTextArea);
    panel.add(butt);
     butt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 

                {
                jTextArea.setText("");
                }


              });
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(false);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                  try
                  {
                        new TestPeriodHighlight();
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TestPeriodHighlight.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }

                }
                }
                );

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @JoeyRohan: thanks for this solution. this is working. but here i've some problems. 1) it accepts only 1 line as input. what i should do to read an entire paragraph. 2) The frame is created after entering text, but i want the swing to be created and then enter the text in it. and there once i hit clear, it should highlight the things. Really thank you for the above code.

Comment: How do i give multiple line input and that to in the frame that i created

Comment: As i said, it's just an example.If you want to take a paragraph using GUI,make two  `JTextArea ` one to read, second to display result.2) Second one is simple.I have done  `frame.setVisible(false) ` make it  `frame.setVisible(true) ` .3) Do highlighting part in the  `ActionListener ` block of  `JButton butt ` . :)

Comment: Thanks for this. will ping you if i face any problem.

Comment: this is very confusing, can you please provide the code for this? i'm really sorry for asking. i also need to update the code that you provide with various excetions.

Comment: @MarsoniNm Show me what have you tried.

Comment: i've updated what i've tried, but this is not working one and also not a fully done one. actually i'm unable to know how to start and how to proceed .

Comment: i've updated it in my question.

Comment: Read text from  `jTextArea2 `.Ask user to input through `jTextArea2 `.No need of scanner then.If u have much problem, convert the string of `jTextArea2 ` into `toCharArray()` and then process the text.Try.

Comment: user enters text in textarea1 and once button click is done. the second textarea should place the formatting things

Comment: textarea2 should look like this  `jTextArea2.setText(jTextArea1.getText()) ` but leave it for now.remove ` jTextArea2=jTextArea1.getText()`  stmt.(Should give error).Do processing first.Will tell you a simple way.1) change the text from textarea1 toCharArray and store it in char array.Then check for dots.Try.

Comment: ok thanks. i'll try and let you know